# How to find out existing user-name and password on wamp server of drupal

Tags: drupal, wamp

I have installed drupal-7 on wamp-server (localhost), i was using it very well because it was logged in    with username and password(remembered), but now don't know how it is asking for user-name and password (because it is logged-out) that is i forgot .. i tried to change the password but but seriously i confused can any one help me

and error is **"PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'qdro_drupal'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of C:\wamp\www\site\includes\lock.inc)."**

Comment: try with drush uli if the SQL error is gone.
This SQL error may occur when your mysql server crashed, try to restart it (I don't know how to do it in wamp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to fix it is re-installing Drupal, in my opinion. It seems the Database has created wrong, and your users table is corrupted.

Try to create another user via dashboard, and then, change the value of the root user in settings.php. In $database variable. It may fix your problem.

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

That is for your mysql not for Drupal. You need to reset your mysql password, not Drupal. The issue is while connecting with your database

Comment: Haha! This is not about creating the db. This is about your database credentials. You need to edit settings.php file in sites/default/ directory and confirm that you are using correct database username & password. Most probably, on a local machine, using wapm, that will be 'root' and no passoword. From your error message, it appears that you have downloaded the site from the server and tried to use locally.